# A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause c#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

While this is a frequently asked question I have not found a solution that fits my situation.

I am receiving the above compile error on the following code:

```
var data = from g in db.MD_import_results
    .Where((fProjectID == tProjectID) && (g.md_CheckResults) != null 
    || (g.md_CheckResults1) != null || (g.md_CheckResults2) != null 
    || (g.md_CheckResults3) != null).Select(
            p => new
            {
                p.AccountID,
                p.md_HouseNumber,
                p.md_StreetPreDirectional,
                p.md_StreetName,
                p.md_StreetSuffix,
                p.md_StreetPostDirectional,
                p.md_Suite,
                p.md_City,
                p.md_State,
                p.md_ZipCode,
                p.md_CheckResults,
                p.md_CheckResults1,
                p.md_CheckResults2,
                p.md_CheckResults3,
                p.ProjectID
            });
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Just get rid of the `from g in` part since you seem to be using method syntax anyway.

Comment: Don't use the 'from' syntax.  Use Following : var data = db.MD_import_results.Where(............

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to write LINQ queries, **query syntax** and **method syntax**.

Query syntax looks like

```
from g in x
  where g.foo == bar
  select g.baz;
```

Method syntax looks like

```
x.Where(g => g.foo == bar).Select(g => g.baz);
```

You have combined the two. You started writing `from g in x` and then continued writing `.Where(...)`.  Pick one syntax and stick with it.